# Write the output of an lxml parse to a new file

Tags: xml, file, lxml

I have been receiving help on this forum to parse an xml file and pull out certain values.  I can successfully print the required values to the screen, using the below:

```
for info in root.xpath('//xmlns:ProgramInformation', namespaces=nsmap):

   print (info.get('programId')) # retrieve crid
   print (info.find('.//xmlns:Title', namespaces=nsmap).text) # retrieve title
   print (info.find('.//xmlns:Genre/xmlns:Name', namespaces=nsmap).text) # retrieve genre
```

I now need to write the output to a file (not in XML format but in the format ABC|DEF|GHI, with each set on a new line).

I experimented with fo.write (which I have used elsewhere), but this doesn't appear to be the solution.  I also looked at the element tree 'write' command, but I don't understand how to implement it.

Can someone advise how to construct the strings from the lxml output and write it to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the output file using [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) with the write mode (`w`), then use [`file.write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) to write to the file.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for info in root.xpath('//xmlns:ProgramInformation', namespaces=nsmap):
       crid = (info.get('programId')) # retrieve crid
       title = (info.find('.//xmlns:Title', namespaces=nsmap).text) # retrieve title
       genre = (info.find('.//xmlns:Genre/xmlns:Name', namespaces=nsmap).text) # retrieve genre
       f.write('{}|{}|{}\n'.format(crid, title, genre))
```